# Macbook restarts repeatedly while sleeping

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, logs

Last night, my macbook (10.13.4) was sleeping while low on power. I got on it this morning and the battery was dead. After charging, I noticed that if I close the lid to put the computer to sleep, it will restart over and over again. The same thing happens while I tell the computer to sleep via the menu or terminal with `pmset`. The restart cycle continues -- the computer will reboot to the login screen, eventually go to sleep, and then reboot about 30 seconds after starting to sleep. There are no visible error messages, but chrome will complain of an improper shutdown if it was open during the last session before sleep.

disk utility says nothing is wrong, I've seen similar issues that suggested removing the sleep image and reseting the pram and smc. The issue persists in safe boot.

If i look at the logs (`log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h`), when the restart cycle continues I will see entries like:

`2018-07-06 11:08:41.767136-0400 0xb1       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -128`

Cause `-128` looks to be a possible memory or hardware issue from what I can tell. But the apple hardware test does not show any issues. And these are my `pmset` settings:

```
~ % pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              0
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by AddressBookSourceSync)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: If you see a shutdown cause of "-128", it's a hardware issue.  Your next step is to run [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: thanks @Allan -- I ran it yesterday and everything came up fine

Comment: I would take it in to Apple as it's pointing to a hardware issue and AHT isn't robust enough to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

if the issue persist in safe mode,  it means that is either an issue in the whole software or even a problem in the logic board.

to isolate the issue try the next steps:

Create a new user and set the computer to sleep, if issue is not reproduced you can migrate the data from one user to another.

if issue is reproduced and you have a time machine backup to date where everything is fine restore the backup to isolate the problem, if you do not have the backup , try removing the next file :  macintoshHD/library/preferences/powermanagement.plist and perform a PRAM

if you still have the problem, backup your files and erase and install

if you still have the problem, you will have to take it to service. if it is hardware it is normally the logic board the problem.

good luck

Comment: thanks -- would a logic board issue show up in disk utility or anywhere else? i do have the same issues w/a new user. I found this report of other users which makes me wonder if it's a problem with the os https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8342712

Comment: You could try to start holding down ALT + D keys while restarting, this will launch apple hardware test. However, if issue is intermittent, it will not be reflected immediately. If there is a possibility that the issue is related to the last update 10.13.4. You can erase and install (bacing-up first) from Internet recovery. ALT + CMD + R + Shift. This will allow you to install the os x that came built-in with your computer. So if issue is reproduced in that version, it is hardware, if issue is not reproduced, it is the last version so your choice will be to update to a version before 10.13.4.

Answer (score 0):

- Update to 10.13.5
- Reset your SMC (if updating doesn't resolve)
- Make sure there are no magnetic sources nearby. It could be improperly triggering some of the internal sensors.

Good luck!